# ExtAudioFileRead, Conversion, looping

Tags: ios5

I'm having a hair-pulling moment here, trying to adapt the MixerHost sample code to be more memory efficient using a circular buffer. But the problem seems to occur simply when I change the code from reading the entire Audio File to reading just a chunk of 4K bytes.  The Audio File is indeed compressed, so the clientFormat is LPCM and there is an implicit conversion that takes place, just as in the sample code. But when I read smaller chunks, the data that is collected into the bufferList  (AudioBufferList *) seems to be different. And it depends on the number_of_frames parameter in the ExtAudioFileRead() call:

```
ExtAudioFileRead (
                  audioFileObject,
                  &numberOfFramesToRead, // <- this set to chunk size in bytes
                  bufferList   // <- contains 2 buffers, 1 chan each for L, R
                 );
```

Q: Is the number of frames to read supposed to mean that number in the OUTPUT Format? So, if I specify 1024 frames, I'll get 1024 L,R samples read to simple LPCM format?
Q: Why would I get different results if the number of frames per read is different?

SDK: iOS 5.1